# How do I add a script to page.tpl.php only for anonymous users?

Tags: theming, javascript

I want to do something like this, but it seems like I'm missing something.

```
<?php
  if (user_is_anonymous()) {
    print <script></script>
  }
?>
```

Comment: It is great that you have found a solution to your question, but please do not edit it into the question. Instead use the button at the bottom to answer the question yourself :). (You should be able to accept it in a few hours/days)

Comment: Thanks I'm new here and was not able to use reply since my account was new - now it works

Comment: No problem. By asking good questions and accepting answers you will gain reputation in no-time. You can [take the tour](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour) and/or scroll though the [help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea of other things this site has to offer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the obviously invalid PHP (which I'm assuming is just the result of your snippet, and that your actual code is at least syntactically valid), no, you're not missing anything. That's the correct way to conditionally add a script to a template.

The only logic improvement you can make is to use the `$logged_in` variable which is already available to page.tpl.php. As a style/convention improvement, you could also follow Drupal's standards and use the alternate block syntax:

```
<?php if (!$logged_in): ?>
<script>...</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I updated my question which I got from a user on irc

Comment: There's no point in using `user_is_anonymous()`, that decision has already been made for you. Use `!$logged_in` instead, and also don't include your javascript in a string - you're in a template file, it's not appropriate!

Comment: I switched to your solution Clive and it works fine. Thank you for making it cleaner

Answer (score 1):

If you go to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21page.tpl.php/7.x

and scroll down a bit and click on `view source` you'll see in the comments there is a `$logged_in` variable that you can use.

so simply do

```
if ($logged_in == FALSE) {
  // your PHP code
}
```

[image]